# Reason for experiencing electric current flowing through body during sleep from top to bottom

Tags: reference-request, sleep, dreams, sensation

I know about [sleep paralysis](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/sleep-paralysis/) and there is several information about it,  available over literature.

> Sleep paralysis is a temporary inability to move or speak that occurs
> when you're waking up or falling asleep.

But I never read about sensations of some electric current passing through an individual as shown in this [figure](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/humanoid-robot-glowing-energy-circles-600w-49279639.jpg) from top to bottom during sleep. It doesn't comes under the category of sleep paralysis.

When I searched over internet [[1]](https://www.quora.com/Why-can-I-make-my-body-feel-like-electricity-is-running-through-it-at-will), I found almost no proper material to read science behind it.

Is there any research done on (or at-least recognition in literature on existence of) **such** sensations while sleeping?

Comment: The self-help component has been successfully eliminated by your edits, but I leave it closed as its still based on anecdotal evidence - The sensation of current flowing is not framed in terms of Psych or Neurosci.

Comment: @AliceD I am hoping that the dream tag supports the question. Do u mean that it  was never dealt in literature?

Comment: @hanugm I'm still not clear on what this question is about.  The concept of "sensations while sleeping" is confusing to me, as people don't generally have sensations while sleeping (that's kind of the point).  If you are referring to dreaming of being electrocuted, then the question should say that (though note that it won't help this question as we don't do [dream interpretation](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/643/7001) here).  If you are referring to something else, then please clarify.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg - Perhaps OP is talking in context of sleep disorders like the *Restless Leg Syndrome* (RLS) where they experience sensations like itching, crawling, pulling, aching, throbbing, or pins and needles (mostly in the legs but sometimes on another body parts too)? [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/brain/restless-legs-syndrome/restless-legs-syndrome-rls#2) suggests it is often treated with psychiatric medication like dopaminergic drugs, sedatives, narcotic pain pills or even anticonvulsant or antiseizure drugs.